# Want to hotkey 3 keys to 1 key with Mac

Tags: hotkeys

For Windows you can use AutoHotKey, but I have a Macbook, does anyone have any suggestions on what to do? I want to write a script to hotkey the keystrokes 1, 2, 3 to just 1 with a 15 millisec delay between the 3 keys. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's an app called [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/), available in Mac App Store.

Answer (score 0):

[IronAHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=54494)... not sure if there is a more recent version